# Generalized change of variables in integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

When I read the following (http://www.math.helsinki.fi/~analysis/GraduateSchool/maly/gs.pdf ),
it is hard to understand it. In particular, what does it mean by the last equation? Why does it make sense?

[image]